# Problem with transforming a string date to a datetime variable in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, date, datetime

I have a variable called `FOUNDATION_DATE` which includes the following date observations in string format:

```
'01/Jan/12'
''
''
''
'01/Jan/08'
''
'01/Jan/44'
''
''
'14/Oct/08'
''
''
'12/Jul/04'
'03/Aug/05'
'20/Apr/10'
'30/Dec/98'
'09/Apr/16'
'01/Jan/10'
'01/Dec/01'
'01/Jan/93'
```

I am using the Matlab function `datetime` to transform the above observations in `datetime` data type. The code is

```
datetime(FOUNDATION_DATE,'InputFormat','dd/MMM/yy')
```

which provides the following results:

```
01-Jan-2012
NaT
NaT
NaT
01-Jan-2008
NaT
01-Jan-2044
NaT
NaT
14-Oct-2008
NaT
NaT
12-Jul-2004
03-Aug-2005
20-Apr-2010
30-Dec-1998
09-Apr-2016
01-Jan-2010
01-Dec-2001
01-Jan-1993
```

While for the majority of the cases the transformation is conducted properly, for the observation `'01/Jan/44'` this is not the case as the year becomes `2044`. This issue appears in many other date observations of my variable (only a small sample is presented here) and it is quite strange that this issue appears for date observations for years before 1969.

Does anyone have a solution for accurately transforming these strings to `datetime` variables? Any explanation also why this happens?

Comment: Have a look at the [datetime help](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html). There is an option called `PivotYear`, which says: _Start year of the 100-year date range in which a two-character year resides [...]_ The default is `year(datetime('now')) - 50` which is 1969 as of today. Set `PivotYear` to `year(datetime('now')) - 99`, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `'PivotYear'` option, which defines which 100-year date range the 2 digit date refers to:

```
datetime( '01/Jan/44', 'inputformat', 'dd/MMM/yy', 'pivotyear', 1930 )
```

So here the 100-year range is 1930 - 2029

The default as [documented](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) (therefore not very "strange"), is

```
year(datetime('now'))-50 % = 1969 at time of writing (2019)
```

Comment: Is it possible to enlarge this 100-year range?

Comment: @Whitebeard13 Logically it's impossible - how would you expect Matlab to handle 2019 (written as just "19") if your date range was 1900 to 2099?

Answer (score 1):

When only 2 years are represented matlab makes an assumption on what the first two digits are, you can override this by:

```
startYear = year(datetime('now')) - 99;
datetime('01/Jan/69', 'InputFormat', 'dd/MMM/yy', 'PivotYear', startYear)
```

That will make any dates in 2 digits up until today be historic.